# Decompiling a self generated jar in lib in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prototype"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    testCompile 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:0.31'
}
```

I have generated a jar using swagger codegen and have placed in `lib` folder of my app in the Android studio. It is not getting decompiled, i.e., I am not able to see classes of my jar here.
I have tried **Invalidate caches/Restart**. It worked sometimes before.
But it is not working anymore. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it android project? What build tool do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me :

> 1. Right-click the jar file.
> 2. Select 'Add as Library.
> 3. Do Gradle Sync.

Answer (score 1):

You probably missing in your `build.gradle` something like:

```
compile files('libs/your-jar-filename.jar')
```

Comment: I have added compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) in my build.gradle.

Comment: And you don't see library yet after sync?

Comment: No I am unable to see it.I have inserted the snapshot above in que.

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`? The Same configuration works for me, I can see jar content

Comment: I see nothing wrong in it. So I will delete my answer since it doesn't help